# permission error in python while accessing system files

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm trying to write a program with python which blocks some websites in certain hours.for this I have to change the hosts file in windows.I used the following code:

```
 import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
hosts_path = "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
weblist = ["www.youtube.com", "youtube.com", "www.zoomg.ir",
           "zoomg.ir", "www.rooziato.com", "rooziato.com"]

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,6) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 20):
        print("It's working hours")
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in weblist:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in weblist):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()

        print("It's not working hours")

    time.sleep(5)
```

the code works fine when I use the copy of the hosts file but when I want to use it on the original file I have to run as administrator the cmd and open the program from there.But as soon it reaches this line of the code:

```
with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
```

this is the tracback:

```
File "Blocker.py",line 11min <module>
   with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
PermissionError:[Errno13]Permission denied:"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc"
```

what should I do?

Comment: doesn't seem to be a python-specific problem. I bet you can reproduce that with a .bat file. can you show us the traceback?

Comment: You do not have access to this file. Try running a shell as administrator. And then execute the python script from it.

Comment: @Utsav         I ran the shell as administrator and that error appeared

Comment: @FarzinNasiri add traceback to your question in code formatting, not in comment

Comment: Your path to the `hosts` is incomplete. It only goes to `etc` which is a directory. Of course you cannot open that

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you very much.The problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You are running the script with a Windows-User that has no permissions to open the original file (file at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers)

Have you tried to grant permissions on that folder to your user?

If you have access to an Admin user, grant permissions to the user that will run the Python script, on the folder C:\Windows\System32\Drivers

This [article](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer) might help